# Проблема с button JAVA (android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Всем привет. Решил сделать простенькое приложение для "изучения" английского. Реализую сейчас систему карточек (т.е. нажимаю на кнопку, выскакивает слово, нажимаю еще - снова новое слово). Но моя проблема заключается в том, что при нажатии на кнопку слово появляется, но делает это один раз. Один раз нажал, одно слово показало и на этом все благополучно заканчивается. Сколько нажимай не нажимай - фиолетово. Подскажите что делать в данной ситуации? 
P.S. за говнокод извиняюсь. Пробовал много всего и ничего не помогало(

```
public class Word extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView MainTextView;
TextView detailed;

public int levelint = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_word);
    MainTextView = findViewById(R.id.TextWordTable);
    detailed = findViewById(R.id.detailed);

}


public class WordList {
    String[] level1 = {"an Apple","a House","a Man","an Apple","a House","a Man","a Xui"};
    String[] leveldetal = {"Яблоко","Дом","Мужыг"};
    String[] level2 = {"a Boy","A girl","level 3"};
    String[] level3 = {"ss","level 2","level 3"};
    int step = 0;


}

public void onClick(View v) {

    WordList allWord = new WordList();
    //for (int i = 0; i < allWord.level1.length; i++) {
        //MainTextView.setText(allWord.level1[i]);
        //detailed.setText(allWord.leveldetal[i]);
        if (levelint == 0) {
            String disp = new String(allWord.level1[allWord.step]);
            MainTextView.setText(disp.toString());
            allWord.step++;
            if (allWord.step == 10) levelint++;
            allWord.step = 0;
        } else if (levelint == 1) {
            MainTextView.setText(allWord.level2[allWord.step]);
            allWord.step++;
            if (allWord.step == 10) levelint++;
            allWord.step = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас **WordList allWord = new WordList();** ограничен областью метода onClick(..). Т.е. объект создается, выводит текст 1 карточки, делает step = 1 и по завершению метода onClick объект удаляется. При следующем нажатии на кнопку, всё повторяется снова.
Вынесите объявление WordList allWord из метода, сделайте его глобальным, и всё будет работать хорошо

Comment: Я перенес его в начало класса и ничего не изменилось :(

Comment: **if (allWord.step == 10) levelint++;
            allWord.step = 0;**
это оба действия разве не должны быть под { } вместе? Без объединения их в блок, у вас после каждого нажатия на кнопку, step становится равен 0. Всегда. Действие if на него не распространяется в данном случае

Comment: вот ты глазастый. заработало) спасибо большое)